# PIG script not running through cronjob

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, cron, apache-pig

This is my sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME="/home/admin/software/java/jdk1.7.0_51"
export PIG_HOME="/home/admin/software/PIG/pig-0.14.0"
export PIG_CONF_DIR="$PIG_HOME/conf"
export PIG_CLASSPATH="$PIG_CONF_DIR"
export PATH="$PIG_HOME/bin:$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
cd /home/$USER/testshadoop
pig -x local -param data='Delhi' executequery.pig
```

And this my crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * * /home/admin/testshadoop/test1.sh >> /home/admin/testshadoop/test_out.log
```

If I run the sh file directly in the terminal, it's working fine, but through cronjob, it's not working.

Why, and how can I fix it?

Comment: And what are the permissions of `test1.sh` file?

Comment: read, write, execute all the permission given to him.

Comment: You have to explain what "not working" means. What happens exactly?

Comment: "Not Working means" by using cronjob, sh file is not running in which pig script execution command is written.